# Error: npm install -g angular-cli npm ERR

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

```
npm i
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...lar/compiler-cli/-/co'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/lookang/.npm/_logs/2020-05-20T09_09_02_104Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error simply follow these steps the solution is  to reinstall Angular CLI after clearing npm cache

```
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```